# Approaching an automated system that uses a daily database entry

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database-design, meteor

I'm working on a system to manage students in a boarding school that replaces a needlessly complex amount of paperwork. As part of this, some students are not boarders and as such leave the school daily to go home. The paperwork system involves printing out a list of non-boarding students each day, and the students check themselves off as they leave.

I replicated this system using Meteor, but I'm lead to believe my system is fundamentally flawed, and at the very least it is incredibly prone to bugs. I created a database of 'tickets'. Each ticket records the history of a particular non-boarding student during the course of a particular day. In order to initialize the tickets, the server executes the following function every day at midnight using a cron job.

```
function insertDailies() {
console.log("Daily Tickets Generated")
var dailyStudents = Meteor.users.find({"profile.daily": true}); //Insert all daily students
dailyStudents.forEach(function(dailyStudent) {
    Dailies.update({ //Dailies is a collection of these tickets 
            student: dailyStudent,
            date: today().toDate() //Using moment.js
        }, {
            $setOnInsert: {
                student: dailyStudent,
                date: today().toDate(),
                left: false,
                dinner: false,
                stayLate: false,
                sleep: false,
                room: null
            }
        }, {
            upsert: true
    });
});
```

}

where `left`, `dinner`, `stayLate`, and `sleep` are four non mutually exclusive states each student can have.

The current system would be acceptable, only it's incredibly bug prone and unreliable - in some cases, the system will generate two tickets for each student. When accessing the system shortly after midnight in a timezone other than UTC, the tickets will occasionally fail to appear at all. Plenty of other time-related bugs occur that seem to be caused by tying the system to the date.

Is there a better, more bug-resistant approach to keeping track of the state of each student once daily? Is the time-dependency (rather than an event-driven dependency like most other actions) going to force the unreliability to continue even if I replace the current system with something else?

Comment: Have you tried running the cronjob at 3am to see if it fixes some of the time issues?

Comment: What does updating/accessing of the tickets look like? Why not just create them as the four states are changed with an upsert?

Comment: Is `today()` doing something like `moment().startOf('day')`?

Comment: @jeff, I have, but that didn't cause a significant improvement. The system wasn't reliable.

Comment: @MatthewForr, the upsert is meant to prevent the creation of duplicate tickets (because it's being combined with setOnInsert). It resets the data if a ticket already exists for that student, instead of creating a whole new ticket.

Comment: @DavidWeldon, `moment.utc().startOf('day');` to be exact